# I cannot share files between two laptops

Tags: windows-10, laptop, file-sharing, homegroup

I have two laptops at home and need to share files between them.
I tried HomeGroup but the other PC does not find the first one!
Both have windows 10 installed and are connected to a TP-Link wireless dsl modem.

Comment: If your Windows 10 computer or device can’t view other computers on the network, two things are probably at fault: You either assigned the incorrect network profile (public instead or private) or network discovery is turned off for some reason???

Answer (score 2):

If you are on WiFi, the router or access point probably has AP Isolation enabled. Its there specifically to block communications between AP clients.

Check this setting:

```
• AP Isolation: Select this check box to enable the AP Isolation feature that allows you
to confine and restrict all wireless devices on your network from interacting with each
other, but still able to access the internet. AP isolation is disabled by default.
```

Comment: Thanks, but my modem does not have such settings. It's name may be different.

Answer (score 0):

install "LAN share" on both computers and you can transfer files. "LAN share" is for Linux, Windows and MaxOS. See [this link](https://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2018/05/transfer-files-ubuntu-windows-wifi-network)

Answer (score 0):

As long as you create a share on windows using the setting in the properties menu, you should be able to navigate to that share using: *Computername\Foldername*

Also, what version of windows are you using? Did you already install the windows 1803 update? I'm asking because Microsoft decided to remove the homegroup option.

Comment: I cannot ping the other computer. I tried Advanced IP Scanner. It found my phone but not the other laptop! But both laptops have internet access.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried checking the network discoverability check within the control panel? It can be found in Control panel/Network and Internet/Network and sharing Centre/Advanced sharing settings? Or are you using some sort of firewall/antivirus? Have you tried turning those off? [image]